# Responsive Absolute Positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a hover effect to each speech bubble in the image below that link to a different page when clicked on.

Currently, I am using an image map and whenever an area of is hovered over jQuery changes the whole image to be the appropriate image that has the speech bubble filled in. It kind of works but IE flickers every time a hover happens and the website is responsive so the image map does not scale when the screen size is changed. I've tried using https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps too but it doesn't seem to work on a mobile device.

Ideally I'd like to be able to have the speech bubbles be separate images that are positioned correctly when scaled so I can manipulate the speech bubbles easier.

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of image]

Comment: Questions posted on StackOverflow stay forever as a knowgedgebase however links external images (particularly images) get broken over time. When posting it is better to embed the screenshot. I have done it for you.

Comment: @bhantol by the way, I believe OP does not yet have the reputation to embed images.

Comment: I learn new - every day. I did not know that there is such a restriction.

Comment: Sorry @bhantol I tried adding an image and it said I wasn't able to since I just joined.

Comment: Thx for trying..gave you +1 earlier...you deserved it ... In the hind sight.

Comment: I solved this by creating an SVG image using Adobe Illustrator. You can add ID's or classes to elements in an SVG then use CSS to manipulate the shapes to do what you want. Then I added anchor tags around the elements to link to the different pages.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with approach which uses scaled coordinates.

Here's the basic idea:

```
 var coordManager = {
        "imageBaseHeight":800,
        "imageBaseWidth":800,
        "imageID":"myImg",
        "baseCoordinateActions" = [
            {"x":10,"y":10,"h":100,"w":100, "text": "Mousing over first option"}, // the square you want the mouseover to cover for a given action
            {"x":200,"y":200,"h":100,"w":100, "text": "Mousing over first option"}
        ],
        "scaledCoordinateActions" : [], // this should contain the baseCoordinateActions with the scaled values
        "init" : function(id, baseHeight, baseWidth)
        {
           var self=this;
           this.imageID=id;
           this.imageBaseHeight=baseHeight;
           this.imageBaseWith=baseWidth;
           var img = document.getElementById(id);
           img.onresize =function()
            {
                // regenerate the scaled coordinates based on the difference between the imageBaseHeight and the current height;
                // usually you can get the scale by dividing the imageBaseHeight by the actual height
            };
            image.onmousemove = function(event)
            {
                // check the mouse location based on scaled coordinates if it's within the scaled coordinates of any of the scaledCoordinateAction items
                // display that scaleCoordinateAction item's text using the current eventX and Y, or do it relative to the coordinateACtion X and Y.
                // make sure to check if the bubble is already showing before changing the display: property to avoid flicker.
            }
        }
    };

    coordManager.init("imageID", 800,800);
```